# ListView.builder inside FutureBuilder - RenderFlex overflowed error

Tags: flutter

Following code will generate Renderbox overflow error with yellow stripes on screen:

```
class AppntList extends StatefulWidget {
  // Make list api req and show all appnts
  DateTime? appntDate;
  String appntStatus;
  final String listUrl = 'xyz/';

  AppntList({this.appntDate, required this.appntStatus, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AppntList> createState() => _AppntListState();
}

class _AppntListState extends State<AppntList> {
  Future<Response> getAppntsList() async {
    return await makeAuthenticatedGetReq(url: widget.listUrl);
  }

  Widget appntListViewBuilder(List<Map> respBody) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 500,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: respBody.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(respBody[index]['appnt_datetime'] ?? ''),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Response>(
      future: getAppntsList(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Response> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          } else {
            if (snapshot.data?.statusCode == 200) {
              var respBody = jsonDecode(snapshot.data?.body ?? '');
              return appntListViewBuilder(respBody);
            } else {
              return Center(child: Text('Error ${snapshot.data?.statusCode}'));
            }
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Error - `A RenderFlex overflowed by 99210 pixels on the bottom.`

```
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.
```

If I copy all code from `appntListViewBuilder` into `FutureBuilder` and get rid of appntListViewBuilder then it works fine.

Comment: what is the parent widget of `FutureBuilder`

Comment: Where are you using `appntListViewBuilder` and try using `shrinkwrap : true` inside the `listViewBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that You are using **AppntList** widget inside Column. Try wrapping **AppntList** with **Expanded** inside Column's *children* list as error text suggests :)